# angular2 + unexpected token :

Tags: angular, jsonp

In my Angular2 code, I'm trying to get Google Trends keywords via this URL http://hawttrends.appspot.com/api/terms/?callback=JSONP_CALLBACK

It converts the last bit into this:
[http://hawttrends.appspot.com/api/terms/?callback=**ng_jsonp**.__req0.finished](http://hawttrends.appspot.com/api/terms/?callback=__ng_jsonp__.__req0.finished)

and when I check my Network tab, I see the 200 response but it returns the "unexpected token :" error in my console
**Expected/desired behavior**
What I'm looking for is a way to fetch the google trends and use them in my app.
I tried Http(), Jsonp() and even pure XMLHttpRequest() methods. 
The google server for trends does not provide CORS (as you know according to whois info, appspot.com belongs to google) so Http() and XMLHttpRequest() are not working and the Jsonp approach returns with the error I mentioned.
To be honest I'm not sure if I should call it a bug. Because JSONP works fine for other urls (i.e. wikipedia). But since appspot.com is owned by Google I wonder if you could give an insight .
**My environment:**

- **Angular version:** 2.0.0-rc.4
- **Browser:** [ Chrome 51.0.2704.103 ]
- **Language:** [TypeScript 1.8.9 | ES6/7 | ES5]